# Menu loop - order need

Tags: java, loops

Hello this is part of my model, and it repeats till 5 is the input:

```
public static void choice() {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose menu item:");
    System.out.println("predish");
    System.out.println("headdish");
    System.out.println("desert");
    System.out.println("4");
    System.out.println("5. Exit");
    int choice = s.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
    case 1: System.out.println("1");
    String filePerson = s.next();
    readPersons(filePerson);
    break;

    case 2: System.out.println("2");
    int p = s.nextInt();
    createPersons(p);
    break;

    case 3: System.out.println("3");
    String filePersonWrite = s.next();
    writePersons(people, filePersonWrite);
    break;

    case 4: displayPersons(people);
    break;

    case 5: System.out.println("Bye-bye!");
    //s.close();
    break;
```

I want my model's orders to be ordered so that when the first input is 3, it says "please choose first a predish or headdish", but, when the first input is 1, then it's possible to input 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly a `do-while` loop should work in your case.

```
boolean needDish = true;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Choose menu item:");
System.out.println("predish");
System.out.println("headdish");
System.out.println("desert");
System.out.println("4");
System.out.println("5. Exit");
int choice = s.nextInt();

do {

  switch (choice) {
    case 1: 
      System.out.println("1");
      needDish = false;
      String filePerson = s.next();
      readPersons(filePerson);
      break;

    case 2: 
      System.out.println("2");
      needDish = false;
      int p = s.nextInt();
      createPersons(p);
      break;

    case 3: 
      System.out.println("3");
      if (needDish) {
        choice = s.nextInt();
        break;
      } else {
        String filePersonWrite = s.next();
        writePersons(people, filePersonWrite);
      }
      break;

    case 4: 
      displayPersons(people);
      break;

    case 5: 
      System.out.println("Bye-bye!");
      break;
  }
} while (choice != 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now when I put in 3 the output will be still 3, only when I select 1 or 2 after I put in 3. When my first output is 3 then I need directly to say: "please choose first a predish or headdish

Comment: @user5424264 see the updated answer. I added a check for you